# Java, objectify unique characters from file and count occurrences by increment() method of character object

Tags: java, object, text, character

I am working on a java program that takes a text file as input, creates a "CharacterFrequency" object for each character and counts the # of occurances of each character.  So far I have built the class for the building objects which seems to be functional in its current form but I am having trouble with the logical program flow in my main loop. I cant figure out how to structure my for if else while loops etc to cycle through the characters and increment the count for each object.

Some have asked to clarify so let me try to put it in other terms.

Starting with the first character object, if we loop through the charArray array, I first see a new character, I need to make a new CharacterFrequency object for it then continue to iterate through the charArray and find any more occurances and count them by incrementing using the increment() method of the CharacterFrequency class for that particular character found in the document. The end result is a CharacterFrequency object for each character found and a count of the occurance.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Main Loop:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CharFreqMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //declare variables and object types
        ArrayList<CharacterFrequency> charObjectsArray = new ArrayList<CharacterFrequency>();


        //try to open file and if not found catch file not found exception and exit
        try {
            //create scanner object of text file BufferedReader for efficiency
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/text.txt"));

            //create string to store each line
            String s;

            //while loop reads each line of BufferedReader br and creates string
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {

                //create character array from string s
                char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
                CharacterFrequency newcharobj = new CharacterFrequency();
                System.out.println(charArray);

                //iterate though character array
                for (char c : charArray) {

                    //check if the current object has the same character being checked and increment
                    if (c == newcharobj.getCharacter()) {
                        newcharobj.increment(1);
                    }
                    else {
                        newcharobj.setCharacter(c);
                    }

                    charObjectsArray.add(newcharobj);
                }
            }

            //close BufferedReader br
            br.close();
        }

        //code speaks for itself
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        finally {

            //iterate through objects in charObjs Array and print characters and freqs to console
            for (CharacterFrequency charObject : charObjectsArray) {

                try {
                    System.out.println(charObject.getCharacter() + " | " + charObject.getFrequency());

                }
                catch(NullPointerException e) {

                }

                //build write to file Here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CharacterFrequency Class :

```
public class CharacterFrequency {

    char character;
    int frequency;
    int i;
    int freq = 0;

    public char getCharacter() {
        return this.character;
    }

    public void setCharacter(char character) {
        this.character = character;
    }

    public int getFrequency() {
        return this.frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(int frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public void increment(int i) {
        freq = freq + i;
    }

}
```

This section of code specifically is what I need help with:

```
        //create character array from string s
        char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
        CharacterFrequency newcharobj = new CharacterFrequency();
        System.out.println(charArray);

        //iterate though character array
        for (char c : charArray) {

            //check if the current object has the same character being checked and increment
            if (c == newcharobj.getCharacter()) {
                newcharobj.increment(1);
            }
            else {
                newcharobj.setCharacter(c);
            }

            charObjectsArray.add(newcharobj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem, specifically?

Comment: *I cant figure out how to structure my for if else while loops etc to cycle through the characters and increment the count for each object* is too broad. Would you mind refining your question please? What are you exactly having trouble with,

Comment: Starting with the first character object, if we loop through the charArray array, I first see a new character, I need to make a new CharacterFrequency object for it then continue to iterate through the charArray and find any more occurances and count them by incrementing using the increment() method of the CharacterFrequency class for that particular character found in the document. The end result is a CharacterFrequency object for each character found and a count of the occurance.

Comment: @BrentVaalburg if you're open to solutions using the stream API as of Java-8 then this can be done easily with only 10 lines :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand, it seems that you want to read each line and then build a `CharacterFrequency` object for each character and the number of times it occurs.

This can be easily accomplished with the Java stream API:

```
List<CharacterFrequency> resultSet =
                new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/text.txt"))
                .lines()
                .flatMap(s -> s.chars().mapToObj(a -> (char)a))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> new CharacterFrequency(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

This assumes you have a constructor in the `CharacterFrequency` class as follows:

```
public CharacterFrequency(char character, int frequency) {
      this.character = character;
      this.frequency = frequency;
}
```

Deciphering the above solution:

- The [`lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) method of the `BufferedReader` above yields a
     [`Stream<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), where the elements are the lines read from this
     `BufferedReader`.
- `.flatMap(s -> s.chars().mapToObj(a -> (char)a))` will transform each string to a `Stream<Character>` which `flatMap` then collapses all the nested `Stream<Stream<Character>>` into a single `Stream<Character>`.
- With `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                              Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)))`
  we retrieve a `Map<Character, Integer>` where the key's are the characters and the integer represents the number of occurrences of that given character.
- We then create a stream from the `entrySet` with `.entrySet().stream()` and create `CharacterFrequency` objects with  `.map(e -> new CharacterFrequency(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))`
- Finally, we collect to a list implementation with `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to compile. Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert java.util.ArrayList<E> to C

Comment: @BrentVaalburg what version of java are you using? the code in my answer will only compile if you're using JDK-8 and above. if you're using JDK-8 then what IDE are you using to compile this code?